# Define a commutative rings from a noncommutative one

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be an arbitrary ring. In $R$ define a new binary operation $\circ$ by the rule $a\circ b = a\cdot b+ b\cdot a$ for all $a,b\in R$. Establish that $(R,+,\circ)$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: What happens if you try to establish it yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure that the operation $\circ$ is associative

Comment: yes the problem is in the associativity of the new  operation . the question appears in in David Burton book (introduction to modern abstract algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Take your favorite noncommutative ring, e.g. the tensor algebra $T (M)$. You get then

$$(x∘y)∘z = x⊗y⊗z + y⊗x⊗z + z⊗x⊗y + z⊗y⊗x$$
$$x∘(y∘z) = x⊗y⊗z + x⊗z⊗y + y⊗z⊗x + z⊗y⊗x$$

Which are different things... Or try some examples with the algebra of matrices $M_n (R)$ (where $n = 2$ is enough) to see how associativity fails.

---

The right procedure of making a ring commutative is quotienting out the ideal generated by $(xy - yx)$. This defines the left adjoint functor to the inclusion functor $\mathbf{CRing} \to \mathbf{Ring}$.

Comment: the question is in David Burton book (introduction to modern abstract algebra)

Comment: There is a mistake in that exercise then. As an alternative exercise, you may find, for instance, some 2⨯2 matrices A, B, C such that

(A∘B)∘C = ABC + BAC + CAB + CBA ≠ ABC + ACB + BCA + CBA = A∘(B∘C).

Comment: that is right dear Alejo

Answer (score 0):

By definition, in any ring, the addition is commutative and both operations are associative. So, we have

$$b \circ a=b\cdot a+a\cdot b=a\cdot b+b\cdot a=a\circ b$$

Hence the ring is commutative.

Comment: how to show the associativity property for the new operation